# Problema em consulta em AJAX em um loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

Tenho uma view que possui vários gráficos de pizza, utilizando o plugin D3. Cada gráfico deve exibir dados diferentes.

Com PHP eu faço um foreach na tela, criando as div onde o gráfico será exibido, cada um com uma `id` específica.
Depois com o Javascript eu pego todas essas `id`, e a partir disso, em cada uma das `div` eu faço uma requisição `AJAX` em uma consulta, e os resultados que eu trago, monto cada gráfico.

O problema é que por conta do `AJAX` ser uma consulta assíncrona, constantemente, a ordem de exibição dos gráficos muda, o que não deveria acontecer.

Como posso resolver isso?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    $(".panel-pergunta").each(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('pergunta');
        
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/relatorios/chart/" + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                //console.log(r);
                pieChartData = [];
                total = 0;

                for (var i in r.pesquisas) {
                
                    pieChartData.push({
                        "label": r.pesquisas[i].resposta,
                        "value": r.pesquisas[i].total
                    });
                    total += r.pesquisas[i].total;
                }

                if (total > 0) {
                    nv.addGraph(function () {
                        var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
                                .x(function (d) {
                                    return d.label;
                                })
                                .y(function (d) {
                                    return d.value;
                                })
                                .valueFormat(d3.format(".0f"))
                                .showLabels(true)
                                .showLegend(true)
                                .legendPosition("right")
                                .labelThreshold(0.05)
                                .labelsOutside(true)
                                .labelType("percent")
                                .donut(false)
                                .color(['#EF5350', '#FFA726', '#4DB446'])
                                .donutRatio(0.35);

                        d3.select("#chartp" + id + " svg")
                                .datum(pieChartData)
                                .transition()
                                .duration(350)
                                .call(chart);

                        d3.selectAll('.nv-label text')
                                .each(function (d, i) {
                                    d3.select(this).style('font-weight', 700)
                                })

                        var positionX = 0;
                        var positionY = 0;
                        var verticalOffset = 20;

                        d3.selectAll('#chartp' + id + ' .nv-legend .nv-series')[0].forEach(function (d) {
                            positionY += verticalOffset;
                            d3.select(d).attr('transform', 'translate(' + positionX + ',' + positionY + ')');
                        });

                        return chart;
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#chartp" + id).html("<i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Não há dados suficientes para montar esse gráfico.");
                }
            },
            error: function (r) {
                console.log(r.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor como é que a ordem dos gráficos muda? Estás a usar um `id` unico com `var id = $(this).attr('pergunta');`?

Comment: No código da view eu faço um foreach nas `div` de class `panel-pergunta`. Nessas `div` coloquei um atributo `pergunta`, e o valor do mesmo eu trago do PHP. Então suponhamos, são 13 div, cada um deles com atributo pergunta, de 1 a 13.
Então no javascript faço uma iteração de cada um desses valores, e em cada `div` eu populo o gráfico através dos resultados das consultas.
Porém, dependendo da velocidade que a consulta corre, pode acontecer de a 5ª consulta exibir na 4ª `div`, ou a 8ª, exibir na 7ª, invertendo as ordens aleatoriamente, a cada carregamento da página.

Comment: Se cada `.panel-pergunta` tem um id/atributo unico não faz muito sentido estar a ser misturado. Os unicos erros que vejo assim à primeira vista é não usares `var` na declaração de `pieChartData = []; total = 0;` Isso é importante. Corrige isso e diz se resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que se trabalhar com promisses resolve seu problema:

```
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
var pipe = deferred;
$(".panel-pergunta").each(function () {
  pipe = pipe.then(function () {
    ...seu código...
  });
});
deferred.resolve();
```